# Why Eclipse Ide and Tool Suite won't compile/run my class, just that class which is the main, or a previous one

Tags: java, eclipse, class, runtime-error

yesterday i was trying to run a simple Java class, with a simple method void to print something, when i want to run that class i got something weird... either Eclipse IDE run a different class (a previous one) or don't run at all, just asking for a main class from that package... but why? I mean, if i create a new Maven project, or a new Class, i expect to run that class, but if i want to Run as -> and searching for Java Application, doesn't apper. Anytime i want to run something, either i  neet to run that main class from that particular project/package created or Eclipse running a whole different class from a few days ago when all was good. The same thing i occur in tool Suite...

If you need some photos of configuration or something, feel free to ask, right now i don't know what to do...

Edit: I created a Maven project with a new Class, TestVoidClass with a void method that prints: System.out.println("Inside TestVoidClass");
So now i have two classes in my MavenProject, App class with main method who works fine and i can run that hello world print, and TestVoidClass, who doesn't work, doesn't appear to run as Java Application... bellow are some photos

First photo showing that it's running a previous class:
[image: First photo showing that it's running a previous class]

Second photo showing i can't find that Run as Java application:
[image: Second photo showing i can't find that Run as Java application]

Working with default App maven project main class:
[image: Working with default App maven project main class]

Comment: This: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hello, thanks for showing me that, i just edited my post, you can take a look and maybe a guess, please?

Comment: Your class must have `public static void main(String[] args) { ... }`. Otherwise you can run it as a Java application. You can create the main method by typing `main` and hitting Ctrl+Space.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! I was thinking Eclipse or Ide's in general can run whatever i want but is not like that. Thanks for the help, for the time and for the tip, have a nice day!

Comment: To run it as a Java application, a main method is required (that's the way Java works). To run code snippets you can use a [Java Scrapbook Page](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-create_scrapbook_page.htm).

Answer (score 0):

make sure the class you want to run contains a main-Method. That is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {...}
```

If a class doesn't contain this method, it can't be run. In your main-Method, you can call your Sysout() function.

If you open a class containing a main-Method, Eclipse will automatically run it when you click Launch.